# Recursion fails with a None object

Tags: python, recursion

I want to write a function which returns a list which contains numbers in range. It must return list in reverse order. With the code below I'm always getting the error `"AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'"`.

```
def ret(f,l):
    if f == l:
        e = []
        return e
    else:
        return ret(f+1,l).append(f)
```

What's the proper way to achieve this?

Comment: The function `dondur` (whatever that is…) returns `None`, hence you can't `append` to it.

Comment: Assuming this is a typo and it was supposed to call `ret` recursively: `append` returns `None`, and you're returning that `None` from `ret`…

Comment: Function should return a list. If it doesn't return a list how do i get it to give a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`append` returns `None`, so `ret` returns `None`, and you then fail to `.append` to that. Do either of the following to return a list:

```
l_ = ret(f + 1, l)
l_.append(f)
return l_
```

Or:

```
return ret(f + 1, l) + [f]
```